# Condition for inverse of positive diagonal matrix minus matrix with all rows the same (and all entries positive) having all entries positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider matrix $D-B$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with all positive entries and $B$ is a matrix with all rows the same and all entries positive. Let $D_{ij},B_{ij}$ be the entries of $D,B$. I know that if $D_{ii}=d$ for all $i$ then if $d > \rho(B)$ then $D-B$ is an M-matrix and hence its inverse has all entries nonnegative. Can this be generalized in some way to the case in which $D_{ii}$ are not all the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=D^{-1}B$. Then $D-B=D(I-A)$ is invertible if and only if $I-A$ is invertible. As $A$ is positive, $\rho(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Therefore $I-A$ is invertible if and only if $\rho(A)\ne1$. Suppose this is the case. Since $(D-B)^{-1}=(I-A)^{-1}D^{-1}$, it is positive if and only if $(I-A)^{-1}$ is positive.

Note that when $(I-A)^{-1}>0$, we have $(I-A)^{-1}x>0$ for all nonnegative but nonzero vector $x$. It follows that when $p$ be the left Perron vector of $A$, we have
$$
0<p^T\big((I-A)^{-1}x\big)=\big(p^T(I-A)^{-1}\big)x=\frac{p^Tx}{1-\rho(A)}.
$$
Since $p^Tx>0$, we must have $\rho(A)<1$. Conversely, when $\rho(A)<1$, $(I-A)^{-1}$ can be expanded as a Neumann series and hence it is positive.

So, we conclude that $D-B$ is inverse-positive if and only if $\rho(D^{-1}B)<1$.